# Width not updated when device is rotated

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

So I have this button example

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 40)
```

Why isn't the width updated when the device is rotated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using autolayout, you need to modify the constraints. When the device rotates, it check with the constraints to redraw the contents.

Try something like:

```
let newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)
view.addConstraint(newConstraint)
```